# Bosh CLI Expected to find a map at path '/applications/routes' but found '[]interface {}'

Tags: bash, cloud-foundry, concourse, cf-bosh

I get this error when I run the command:

```
$ bosh int config.yml --path /applications/routes/route
```

> Expected to find a map at path '/applications/routes' but found '[]interface {}'
>
> Exit code 1

This is my `config.yml` file:

```
applications:
- buildpack: php_buildpack
  instances: 1
  memory: 1G
  name: yxyxy
  routes:
    route: preprod-paas.itn.group
  services:
  - maria-db
  - smtp-mail
```

Any help, I'm using bosh CLI V2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your YAML structure includes array with single item.
You need to find an element with this array.
I usually search by name. In your case, it will look like: `bosh int --path /applications/name=yxyxy/routes/route`.

I think it is also possible to get item by index `/applications/0/routes/route`

There is a syntax documentation, that you can check https://github.com/cppforlife/go-patch/blob/master/docs/examples.md

Comment: Thank you, both are working. Is there no official documentation to bosh cli other than this github repo?

Comment: Yes, there is official bosh-cli documentation http://bosh.io/docs/cli-ops-files/. It is a bit more focused on deployment and operations.